# How to add a kernel module on Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, kernel-module, fuse

I would like to add a kernel module on Cygwin, however the `modprobe` command is not supported by Cygwin and I was unable to find any solution to this.

I am interested in this to add Fuse support in Cygwin. I have already done a first quick adaptation to Fuse and have been able to build it on Cygwin (the three steps `./configure && make && make install` are done) but, as described above, the last `modprobe` step doesn't work.

Does someone know where I can find a `modprobe` version for Cygwin or how I can do without it (are there any alternative)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin is not Linux and does not support kernel modules.  Therefore, there is no `modprobe` command, and FUSE will not work on Cygwin.